# Possible way of doPostBack via Link?

Tags: javascript, dopostback

I have the following code but I want to try and find a way to use it as a link e.g roblox.com/doPostBack... so you don't have to click on it. What I mean by this is make the doPostBack via link instead of a button.

Is there anyway I can implement this?

Code:

```
<div id="ctl00_cphRoblox_JoinGroup" class="btn-neutral btn-large" onclick="__doPostBack('JoinGroupDiv', 'Click');" style="margin-top: 10px;">
Join Group
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put it in an anchor link like follows:

```
<a id="ctl00_cphRoblox_JoinGroup" class="btn-neutral btn-large" href="javascript:__doPostBack('JoinGroupDiv','')" style="margin-top: 10px;">My Link</a>
```

However, I think you may be asking if you could create a URL whose sole purpose is to trigger a postback.

I would like to express concern over your reasoning for wanting to do this; however it can be done via setting a query string parameter for the client id you would like to trigger (rewriting can make your URL look pretty). Then take this query string, and write out some javascript on the page in question to fire the postback:

```
<script>
(function() {
   // Call your postback here based on querystring
   var idFromQueryString = '<%= Request.QueryString["controlId"] %>';
   __doPostBack(idFromQuerystring,'')
})();
</script>
```